# Import customer reporting schedule into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

The company I work for has a custom reporting schedule, similar to the month specific groups four or more weeks are grouped into 'periods'. I have a mapping from date to period that I wish to upload to Google Analytics using its data import function.

When I get to selecting the schema on the data import tool there is no option to select the date as the key to join my data on.

Is this possible in Google Analytics? What is the correct method?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is for the most part not possible; imported data is applied to incoming data but not to data that has already been collected, and then it is applied to all hits, not to a specific timeframe. Also you cannot create new interactions, you can only amend or change interaction data as it is being collected.

Google Analytics Premium (now 360) accounts have a feature called query time imports where imported data is applied to existing data in GA. This still does not allow you to selected a date as key, but if you have created a custom dimension and stored a date in there you should be able to make this work (since you can select a custom dimension as key field); however if have not actually tested this, so this is an educated guess.

But for the most part no, this does not work in GA and there is no correct method for your use case.

Comment: Luckily GA premium is available - might it be possible to exploit the custom dimension to make the schedule available?